# Im new with call api , can someone help me with this . Call Api link shortener with javascript

Tags: javascript, html

So I have a mission is call api to this website : https://shrtco.de/ and using link shortener like them. But I don't know how to call it . Can someone explain how to call this or maybe help me , thank you guys so much
This is my HTML code :

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div>
        <p>Enter a link</p>
        <input type="text">
        <button>Enter</button> <br>
        <p>Short domain</p>
  <input type="radio" id="domain1" name="fav_language" value="domain1">
  <label for="html">shrtco.de</label><br>
  <input type="radio" id="css" name="fav_language" value="CSS">
  <label for="css">9qr.de</label><br>
  <input type="radio" id="javascript" name="fav_language" value="JavaScript">
  <label for="javascript">shiny.link</label>
  <p>Link generated</p>
  <a href="">ZZZZZ</a>
    </div>
    <script src="getAPI.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Have you taken a look at the developer api notes? There 's a complete example described. Can you be more specific about your problem? What have you tried so far to call the API?

Answer (score 1):

Following the example from the [interface documentation](https://shrtco.de/docs/), I have programmed a minimal illustrative example here.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <title>shortcode example</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <input type="text" name="url" id="url" value="" required>
        <button id="submit" type="submit">shorten</button>
        <p id="result"></p>
        <script>
            const button = document.querySelector('button');
            const input = document.querySelector('input');
            const result = document.getElementById('result');

            const shorten = (event) => {
                let value = input.value.trim();

                while (result.firstChild) {
                    result.removeChild(result.firstChild);
                }

                if (!value.length) {
                    throw new Error('well! you have to type in something!');
                }

                let promise = fetch('https://api.shrtco.de/v2/shorten?url=' + value);

                promise.then(response => {
                    if (response.status !== 201) {
                        console.log('Looks like there was a problem: ' + response.status);
                        return;
                    }

                    response.json().then(data => {
                        let link = document.createTextNode(data.result.full_short_link);
                        result.appendChild(link);
                    }).catch(error => {
                        console.log(error.message);
                    })
                });
            }
        
            button.addEventListener('click', shorten, false);
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

#### What is happening in this example?

First there are three elements - an input element for typing in the url to shorten, a button element for submitting the data and a paragraph for displaying the results of the api call.

The submit button gets an javascript event listener, that handles click events. Everytime you click on that button, the input element will be checked, if something was typed in. If the value of the input element has a length, it will be send to the shortening service. For that reason we produce a promise with the [javascript fetch api](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch).

The call with the fetch api returns a javascript promise, which we check for the response status code. The api returns a 201 "Created" status code, that says everything is alright. The api needs a little time for the response, but then we can decode the json response and print out the shortened link in the result paragraph.

#### What you should do

Try to understand the given example. Please read the interface documentation to get informations about what could be returned in a success case and whats happening when the request fails? The javascript fetch api is elemental for that.

Try to transfer the given example to your application. If you encounter problems, explain these problems in detail and ask for a solution.